# How to render a native web component in Vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

So i created the following method to render a webcomponent:

```
export function renderComponent(el: Element, component: Component,props: VNodeProps,appContext: AppContext){
let vnode: VNode | undefined = createVNode(component, props)
vnode.appContext = { ...appContext }
render(vnode, el)

return ()=> {
    render(null, el)
    vnode = undefined
}
}
```

i tried using it like this in my componentView.vue:

```
const addComponent = async(component: ComponentRegistryItem) => {
  destroyComp = renderComponent(
    containerDiv.value,
    (await import (/* @vite-ignore */ component.frontendUrl)),
    {},
    appContext);
};
```

And i have this template:

```
       <li v-for="component in group">
        <button @click="addComponent(component)">{{ component.tagName }}</button>
        <div ref="containerDiv"></div>
      </li>
```

the component.frontendUrl is a javascript webcomponent extending HTMLElement (**non vue**), But when i press the button i do not get any error, just nothing happens.

Does any one know how to render a non vue component?

**UPDATE:**

when i log the imported component i see :

```
    Object { … }
​         Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
```

Comment: Have you taken a look to the [Vue documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/web-components.html#using-custom-elements-in-vue) about web components?

Comment: @Kapcash but i can only find examples for Vue components, not non-vue

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Native webcomponent are 100% compatible with Vue with no config required. Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue3-use-webcomponent-8vgekc?file=/src/main.js) using this native webcomponent: [`html-code-block`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/heppokofrontend/html-code-block-element)

Answer (score 1):

You attempt to import with `import()`, except that as you mention in your log, `import()` returns an object containing a module, not the default export, and in order to use your import correctly, you need access to the default import. You can do this by adding `.default` after the `import()`.

```js
const addComponent = async(component: ComponentRegistryItem) => {
  destroyComp = renderComponent(
    containerDiv.value,
    (await import (/* @vite-ignore */ component.frontendUrl)).default,
    {},
    appContext);
};
```